# Displaying Multiples values from Checklist to FPDF form using PHP

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I have a problem with calling values from my checklist and display it in my fpdf form.

This is my fpdf_process.php:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['btn_submit']))
    {
        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
    }
    require("fpdf/fpdf.php");

    $pdf= new FPDF();
    $pdf->Addpage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Times',"", 12);
    $pdf->Cell(0,10,"Welcome",1,1, 'C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Name:", 0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10, "$name", 0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,"Mobile:",0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10, "$mobile", 0,1);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,"Address:",0,0);
    $pdf->Cell(50,10, "$address", 0,1);

    if (!empty($_POST['language[]'])) 
    {
        foreach ($_POST['language[]'] as $selected) 
        {
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,"$selected ", 0,1);
        }
    }

    $pdf->output(); 
?>
```

The selected checklist doesn't show in fpdf_process.php pdf

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php you have errors and the HTML (form) is unknown. `$_POST['language[]` more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

To get the $_POST value you have to know about array's.

Use this

```
$_POST['language'][0];
```

Make sure you named the field also

```
type='checkbox' name='language[]'
```

It would also help you to understand this if you look into the POST value.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: I did the $_POST['language'][0]; and followed what you said, but didn't work. Then I removed the 'foreach' and it displays only one selected checkbox even thou I selected many.

Comment: In the for each you dont need the [0].